# How do I use ST in Idris to get the functionality of ReaderT r Maybe a?

Tags: monads, idris

I've read [the `Control.ST` tutorial](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/st/index.html#implementing-state-aware-systems-in-idris-the-st-tutorial) several times, but I am still not clear on how to use it to implement the kind of effects I would use monad transformers for in Haskell. My specific case is that I want to have something with the same functionality as `ReaderT r Maybe a`; specifically, the following functions:

```hs
ask :: ReaderT r Maybe r
local :: (r -> r') -> ReaderT r Maybe a -> ReaderT r' Maybe a
runReaderT :: ReaderT r Maybe a -> r -> Maybe a
```

How can I use `Control.ST` (and the stuff in it) to implement something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first thing to do is to define an interface to describe the resource managed by the Reader and primitive operations on this resource:

```
interface Reader where
```

We define a custom type for read resources, to control access to them.

```
  Read : Type -> Type
```

We then need a way to introduce and remove read resources:

```
  setRead   : a -> ST m Var [add (Read a)]
  unsetRead : (env : Var) -> ST m () [remove env (Read a)]
```

And of course, `ask` and local:

```
  ask : (env : Var) -> ST m () [env ::: Read a]
  local : (env : Var) -> (f : r -> r') ->
          ST m a [env ::: Read r'] ->
          ST m a [env ::: Read r]
```

From there, we can define `runReaderT` that insert the resource, run a computation that depends on it and delete it:

```
runReaderT : Reader m =>
             ((env : Var) -> ST m a [env ::: Read {m} b]) -> b -> ST m a []
runReaderT f x = do
  e <- set x
  res <- f e
  unset e
  pure res
```

We can now move on to the implementation, relying on `State`:

```
implementation Reader Maybe where
  Read = State

  setRead x = do
    env <- new x
    pure env

  unsetRead env = delete env

  ask env = read env

  local env f st = do
    r <- ask env
    write env (f r)
    x <- st
    write env r
    pure x
```

And then, you're ready to play with it:

```
runReader : (Applicative m, Reader m) =>
            ((env : Var) -> STrans m a [env ::: Read {m} b] (const [env ::: Read {m} b])) ->
            b -> m a
runReader f x = run $ runReaderT f x

incrementRead : Reader m => (env : Var) -> ST m Nat [env ::: Read {m} Nat]
incrementRead env = pure $ 1 + !(ask env)


test : Nat -> Maybe Nat
test y = do
  x <- run (runReaderT incrementRead y)
  guard (x >= 42) *> pure x
```

Hope it helps.